# How can I do nested cross validation for multivariate Time series forecsting

Tags: time-series, cross-validation

I'm trying to do nested CV for my multivariate time series but I'm really confused how to do it. I have 7 Time series which are the inputs of my CNN model and one time series as target.Always when I read about it I found they talk about univariate.Any advices

Comment: The fact that it's multi-variate is irrelevant; the CV is basically done on the indices.

Comment: I didn't understand your point I do have indices